# SSL certified opening on client from the server

Tags: c#, asp.net, x509certificate2

I have to use an SSL certificate on the client, using a web page in ASP.NET which is found on an IIS server.
To do this I try to open x509store. Everything is fine on the development computer, but if I publish on the IIS server I receive the error:
**The current session is not interactive.**
I tried to change your user profile on true, but it doesn't work.
I'm not very practical of asp.net and so I don't know what to do, can you help me?
Sorry if I'm not very clear, but I can add any information you ask me.
This is the code I use and that works on my PC.

```
        public static X509Certificate2 GetCertificate()
        {
            X509Store x509Store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
            X509Certificate2 certSelected = null;
            x509Store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

            X509Certificate2Collection col = x509Store.Certificates;
            X509Certificate2Collection sel = X509Certificate2UI.SelectFromCollection(col, "Title",    "Message", X509SelectionFlag.SingleSelection);

            if (sel.Count > 0)
            {
                X509Certificate2Enumerator en = sel.GetEnumerator();
                en.MoveNext();
                certSelected = en.Current;
            }

            x509Store.Close();

            return certSelected;
        }
```

Comment: Did you take a look at this?

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/7fe93f58-bfa6-4e54-ba0a-b07274bf215b/x509certificate2ui-problem?forum=netfxbcl

The upshot is `X509Certificate2UI` needs a UI which doesn't exist when served from IIS.  For example how would this work on an arbitrary device?

Comment: Thanks @opossum, apparently it is not possible to do what I want with this code, but I can't find a solution suitable for my limited skills.

Comment: What *do* you want to do, and why does it require a UI?

Comment: I need to sign a PDF on the IIS server and I don't need a user interface, but just the ability to read the certificates on the client and use them for signing.

Comment: You need to take whatever logic you as a human were using to pick the signing certificate from the UI and instead move it into program logic by just looking through the contents of `col`.